# How to get 50 characters BEFORE and AFTER a %SQL%?

Tags: php, mysql

### MySQL & PHP

A database row contains a long text.

Now I do this MySQL Query:

```
SELECT text FROM my_table WHERE text LIKE '%value%'
```

That works perfectly.

Now I want to get each 50 characters before and after the fetched %value%. How can I realize that with PHP?

Comment: [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) and [substr](http://php.net/substr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following, where $result is the returned record from your SQL.

```
$excerpt = substr($result, strpos($result, $value) - 50, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in MySQL by doing:

```
select right(substring_index(text, 'value', 1), 50),
       left(substring_index(text, 'value', 2), 50)
from my_table
where text like '%value%';
```